# Integral over a rectangle

Tags: calculus, integration

So my teacher did not explain how to evaluate this. $$\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{3}(x+y)dxdy$$
Can Someone Show Me How To Evaluate This?

Comment: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/IteratedIntegrals.aspx
This may be a useful resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we evaluate the inner integral.
\begin{align}
\int_0^3(x+y)\,dx&=\left.\frac{1}{2}x^2+yx\right|_0^3\\
&=\frac{9}{2}+3y
\end{align}
Then we evaluate the outer integral.
\begin{align}
\int_0^2\int_0^3(x+y)\,dx\,dy&=\int_0^2\left(\frac{9}{2}+3y\right)\,dy\\
&=\left.\frac{9}{2}y+\frac{3}{2}y^2\right|_0^2\\
&=15
\end{align}
Checking answer, see [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_0%5E2%5Cint_0%5E3%28x%2By%29dx+dy). Hope this helps Dan. (>‿◠)✌

Comment: hey, thanks @V-Moy! it's been a long time!

Comment: You're welcome @Dan. Ya, it's been long time. I'm really busy lately. School and course stuff. (─‿‿─)

Comment: you can do it! goodluck! :)

Comment: Thanks @Dan. You too! \（‐＾▽＾‐）/

Comment: Don't stress too much on your studies, though :)

Answer (score 1):

[This site](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/IteratedIntegrals.aspx) helped me a lot when I was learning Double Integrals.

In non-formal terms, "we compute this by holding y constant and integrating with respect to x as if this were a single integral. This will give a function involving only y’s which we can in turn integrate."